# Is there a way to create an IOS project file from a confiiguration file, to avoid having many targets?

Tags: ios, build, targets

We are developing an iOS app which is sold like an OEM product. We are looking at 50+ customers that need to have their own branded app (icons, texts, etc.) and bundle id. The apps are for in-house deployment, not for the appstore.

Is there a way to automatically generate the project file by, e.g. using Ant and a configuration file, so that I don't have to create 50 targets or 50 schemes? Problem with having so many targets is that whenever I, say, add a new library or otherwise change the project file, I have to do repeat it many tines, which is error prone.